# Python: Performing scraping for Applications

Tags: android, python, ios, web-scraping, kivy

I've made a Python program which can get my Timetable and Attendance from my College website. So, for that i used `Selenium` to login into the website and 
collect the stuff with `PhantomJS` for a headless browser, now i want to implement this to an android application so that people at my college can too use this rather that consistently opening the website to check their Attendance on their phone.

My question is that is there any way to achieve this?

I've done some of research and found that [`Kivy`](https://kivy.org/#home) is suitable for this Project, is there any other way by which i can implement it, and could `Jython` be helpful for that?

OR should i go for `kivy` ?

Comment: As this might be opinionbased I will just comment on this. I would give kivy a try. You can package it for both android and ios. https://kivy.org/docs/guide/packaging.html And yes, its achievable if you got the data. Also it might be easier to just ask your colleges it admin, if he will provide the data for you, instead of scrabing.

Comment: @EL3PHANTEN your idea about talking to Admin is great but actually the thing is that , in college we all have a personal erp id's , so to access the Attendance we are supposed to go to the erp page then login, so getting database of all might be not be a very good thing rather than having a dynamic response from the website directly to the application..

Comment: Yes I understand. Eiter way, kivy is, imo, a great candidate for this app :)

Comment: @EL3PHANTEN
i am getting this error while installing kivy using `pip install kivy`

       `  c:\users\user\appdata\local\temp\pip-build-
         r0fj_elc\kivy\kivy\graphics\gl_redirect.h(8): fatal error C1083: 
        Cannot 
         open include file: 'GL/glew.h': No such file or directory
         error: command 'C:\\Program Files\\Microsoft Visual Studio 
         14.0\\VC\\BIN\\cl.exe' failed with exit status 2

         ----------------------------------------
         Failed building wheel for kivy`

Comment: any advice with that?

Comment: did you follow this https://kivy.org/docs/installation/installation-windows.html

Comment: yea i did but when i did `python -m pip install kivy.deps.gstreamer` i gave me an error taht visual studio was missing from my computer so , i installed the setup tools for that, and i think the problem is with the visual studio, because at the end of the installation it says 

`error: command 'C:\\Program Files\\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\\VC\\BIN\\cl.exe' failed with exit status 2`|
what do you think?

Comment: I dont know. I did not have visual studio installed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this problem by installing wheel

i doesn't work on 3.5 or above as the documents say, so you have to choose the appropriate [`wheel`](https://kivy.org/docs/installation/installation-windows.html#install-nightly-win-dist) package according to your python and do the installation of the  `.whl` from the list and then on the terminal do by going to the download directory,

`pip install YourPackage.whl`